# How to fetch specific data from api in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

I am using an API  the name is coming in this API,  but i want to fetch only first two words of the name if the words is greater than two then it should not be fetched. For Example the name is 'Om Prakash Sharma'.So, there are three letter in the name but i just want to fetch only 'Om Prakash' from the API.

```
  List<Qari> qarilist = [];
```

Future<List> getQariList() async {

```
const url = "https://quranicaudio.com/api/qaris";
final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

jsonDecode(res.body).forEach((element){
  if(qarilist.length<20) {
    qarilist.add(Qari.fromjson(element));
  }
});

qarilist.sort((a,b)=>a.name!.compareTo(b.name!)); // sort according to A B C
return qarilist;
```

}

this the api code

Comment: Why don't you convert the the string after receiving the response?

Comment: can you explain little bit more

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: i updated my question with code

Comment: just split the string.

Comment: Can you do this split i am newbie please

Answer (score 0):

```
**//You can try something like the below pseudocode**
List  namelist=[];
String name= "Om Prakash Sharma"; //Om Prakash Sharma
final splitted = name.split(' '); //[Om, Prakash, Sharma]
final splittedlength =splitted.length;//3
if(splittedlength>2)
{
namelist.add(splitted[0]+" "+splitted[1]) ;
print(namelist);
print("in > 2");
}else
{
namelist.add(name);
print(namelist);
print("in else");
}
```

Comment: Tnx buddy i am gonna try this

Comment: np bdy, i changed the answer you just need to add a for each or a for loop for the amount of data you are calculating it'll be stored in namelist after processing

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you:

```
void main() {
  
  List<String> qarilist = ["Mishary bin Rashid.","Ahmad Ali.","Saad ibn Said.","Raad Muhammad"];
  
  var filteredList = qarilist.map((e){
    var nameList = e.split(" ");
    if (nameList.length > 1){
      return "${nameList[0]} ${nameList[1]}";
    } else {
      return e;
    }
  }).toList();
  
  print(filteredList);
}
```

Output:

```
[Mishary bin, Ahmad Ali., Saad ibn, Raad Muhammad]
```